# Where did the reference of banana and cookie come from?

Tags: doctor-who

There are repeating memes and reference regarding the love of banana and cookie of the doctor. Where did they come from?

Comment: He loves bananas and cookies.

Comment: The Eleventh Doctor had a cookie in his pocket and tricked the Daleks into thinking it was a detonator.

Comment: An example meme would go a long way!

Comment: I actually think they started to use Bananas as some kind of hommeage. Back in the day many movies and tv series (as far as they existed) often used common household items in an uncommon way as props, trying to hide their origin. Why not let the Doctor do the exact opposite, using something as common as bananas (which still have a rather unusual shape) to confuse aliens?

Comment: it wasnt a cookie it was Jammy Dodger - in the UK Cookies are a subset of biscuits and not a generic term, The same is true of Custard Creams, Pink Wafers, Garibaldis, Bourbon Creams, Rich Tea, Digestives and of course Jammy Dodgers

Comment: “There are repeating memes and reference regarding the love of banana and cookie of the doctor.” Are there? Where?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Tenth Doctor once said to Rose "Always bring a banana to a party", I believe this is where the meme originated.  The doctor also replaced guns with bananas on two separate occasions to prevent someone from shooting someone else.

The Eleventh Doctor once tricked the Daleks into thinking a Jammie Dodger (a biscuit/cookie filled with jam) was a self-destruct button for the TARDIS.

Comment: "The doctor also replaced guns with bananas on two separate occasions to prevent someone from shooting someone else." Is that besides replacing a whole gun factory with a banana plantation?

Comment: Yeah, the two times I mentioned were with River and Captain Jack.

Comment: Could you tell which episodes?

Comment: The banana plantation one was during The Empty Child (season one of the new series) or the other episode (it's a two-parts story). lonewookie's Captain Jack scene also happened during one of these two episodes as well I think (it's been some time).

Comment: Certainly didn't originate with the Tenth Doctor, as that itself was a reference to a gag from the Ninth Doctor's tenure (specifically, the episode "The Empty Child" as @Mario mentions).

Answer (score 8):

According to the [TARDIS wiki page on bananas](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Banana), the meme goes back quite a while, pre-dating the new series.

> Jo Grant brought a captive Ogron a banana. He did not comprehend her
>   instructions to peel it. (TV: Frontier in Space)
>
> On Space Station Chimera, the Sixth Doctor found a banana whilst
>   searching his pockets for piece of wire. He gave the banana to Peri,
>   who later started to eat it, but gave up when the sight of a dead
>   Androgum made her feel sick. (TV: The Two Doctors)
>
> The Fourth Doctor expressed a fondness for bannanas, once stopping an
>   alien fleet with one. (COMIC: Death to the Doctor!)

<sup>http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Banana#History</sup>

So the banana thing might be a reference to the Third, Fourth and Sixth Doctor.